# How can I retrieve my result everytime in Unity using C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my code

```
public void showMatch (string guess, string regx){
    int outputCode;
    MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches (guess, regx); 
    foreach (Match m in mc) {
        listOfTags [ctr] = m.Value;
        ctr++;
    }

    checkOpeningTag = listOfTags [0];
    checkClosingTag = listOfTags [1];

    if (checkOpeningTag.Equals ("<h1>")) {
        if (checkClosingTag.Equals ("</h1>")) {
            outputCode = 3;
        } else {
            outputCode = 2;
        }
    } else {
        outputCode = 1;
    }
    showError(outputCode);
}

public void showError(int checkError){
    if (checkError == 1) {
        error.text = "Sorry, no opening tag found.";
    } else if(checkError == 2){
        error.text = "Sorry, no closing tag found.";
    }else if(checkError == 3){
        error.text = "You got it right! Advancing to next level!";
    }
}
```

If I try to input <'h1'> and <'h1'> (disregard ') , it will give me an error of

```
Sorry no opening tag
```

But when I try to correct it by submitting <'h1'> and <'/h1'> (disregard '), the error won't update. It still says Sorry no opening tag.

I tried using this code at the end of showMatch function

```
Debug.Log(outputCode);
```

I found that if the first input result is 2, the result everytime will always be 2. Same with if 1 is the result, the next results will be 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you call `showMatch()` function ? The logs keeps getting printed or just one time?

Comment: Couldn't find any reference of listOfTags in your code. It may happen that listOfTags is not cleared each time the showMatch function is called and the  itemse in 0 and 1 index of listOfTags is always the same.

Comment: omg @ZayedUpal im dooooomb. Yeah, I wasn't not resetting the index counter. Thanks hahaha